# index.html in views folder?

Tags: html, node.js, github-pages, web-hosting

I'm not very familiar with node.js, but I've created a website to learn about CSS, HTML, and JS and am now having trouble hosting it. I can run the command `npm start` just fine and then I see my site and all its pages at localhost:3000. However, when I try to upload the site using Github pages or Netlify I always get 404 errors. I think it's because my index.html file is in my views folder so it doesn't know where to look for the first page. I've tried moving everything out of views but this doesn't work, and I've tried making a "dummy" index.html with the following:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/views/index.html">`

which also doesn't work. I'm at a loss for what to do as I'm super inexperienced with this kind of stuff. How can I get my site hosted?

Answer (score 0):

"npm start" only works locally in your machine because you have NodeJS installed. The browser doesn't know anything about npm, it only interprets JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. If you put your "index.html" in the root of your host, it will be found. I suggest you create a structure like a bellow.

```
github pages
  |
  |_ index.html
  |_ css/
  |   |_ styles.css
  |_ js/
  |   |_ scripts.js
```

Commit your changes to github and access your page in /github.io

Comment: I tried this, yet when I take the index.html out of views I get the error: Failed to lookup view "index.html" in views directory

Comment: Please, edit your question. Put some piece of code, this way we can try to help more efficiently.